# Button submit, gets the other buttons from the database

Tags: php

This is my code so far:

```
require_once 'functions.php';
// makes the connection to the server to get the state button names
  $query  = "SELECT state FROM state";
  $result = $connection->query($query);
  if ($result === false) {
  // error mssg
  echo "<p>Query fout.</p>";
}

  // button of the state gets the buttons of the city
  if (isset($_POST['state'])) $state = $_POST['state']; {
  query  = "SELECT city FROM city='$cityid'";
  $result = $connection->query($query);
} if ($result === false) {
  // geef nette foutmelding
  echo "<p>Query fout.</p>";
 }
<?php 

//gives the result to Submit html
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<input type ='submit' name='provincie' value='".$row['provincie']."'>";

}
$result->free();
?>
</for
```

I would like to have a form submit button that gives a variable to PHP, depending on that variable, other buttons are created in the same form. So you can select a country and than you can select the cities in that country. I have the first button up and running. I thought I could just use the same submit button with the same variables. Because php would just rewrite the variables if there is a new input. But I think its not that simple, I don't know how to Google this question or that it is even something I should do with PHP instead of JavaScript/jQuery and just let the buttons hide and display and only use the last one to give an input with PHP.

Comment: This code works partially? This seems like it should error `if (isset($_POST['state'])) $state = $_POST['state']; {`. I think what you're trying to do you should do with AJAX. Send a request, get response, send another request based on initial returned data, right?

Comment: Yeah it works without the: "// button of the state gets the buttons of...$result = $connection->query($query);". I putted that code on to show what i already tried. I tried alot of google, but i dont know what to ask google exactly to solve this problem on my own. Cause iam not looking for just a script to copie and past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do the query result separately, so there should be two while statements

not the best way but here is one way i would do it:

```
      require_once 'functions.php';
      $query  = "SELECT state FROM state";
      if($query->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row= $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                      echo "<input type ='submit' name='provincie' value='".$row['provincie']."' onclick="sendVal(this.value)" >";

                    }   
      }

<script type="text/javascript">
function sendVal(item) {    
    document.cookie="city=" + item + ";";
    location.reload();
}
</script>

<?php 
    if(!is_null($_COOKIE['city'])){     
        $retrievedcities= "SELECT city FROM city WHERE city ='".$_COOKIE['city']."'"; 
        $con->query($retrievedcities);
       while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<input type ='submit' name='citybut' value='".$row['city']."'>";
         }

 unset($_COOKIE['city']);
  }
```

?>